# What is the maths behind Bitcoin?

Tags: governance

I am a math enthusiast. I am now feeling strong interest in bitcoin technology and key research areas. I would like to know what mathematics sub areas are required for bitcoin technology. I am more interested to the application side of bitcoin. For example corporate governance.

Comment: I don't see what corporate governance has to do with a currency.

Comment: I mean actually the decentralized autonomous organization (DAO)

Comment: You may have better luck on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com; there are no DAOs on Bitcoin.

Comment: `SHA-256`, `RIPEMD-160`, `ECDSA`, `SECP256K1`, `PBKDF2`, `HMAC-SHA512`, `BASE58`, `Blockchain`, `Proof of Work`, `Linked List`, `Hash Table`, and `Hash Set` are some keywords you can research.

Comment: @Brandon. Thanks ! You mean that  data structures and cryptography are the main focus?

Comment: @denim, yes, after you are comfortable with the primitives you can move on to layer 2 solutions such as the `Lighting Network` which will require you to know about `Payment Channels`, `Watch Towers`, `Onion Routing`, and `Pickhardt Payments`.  You will also want to know how `BIP32` and `BIP39` are used to grow a wallet from a seed.  `Schnorr` and `SegWit` are also very important concepts to understand.  An easy way to get a tour of every topic mentioned is to just watch `Andreas Antonopoulos` videos.  But you will have to work out some math problems too.

Comment: @Brandon, I see some of the videos of Antonopoulos about bitcoin. However i find most of the lectures are on abstract talks without deep technical details. Therefore i am looking to find some resources for the understanding of Bitcoin technologies ( e.g data structures, networks, payments etc. ) from the computer science engineering point of view. Could you please suggest some of the resources such as lecture notes and textbooks for this purpose? Thanks in advance !

Comment: @denim, "Mastering Bitcoin" and "Mastering the Lighting Network" Andreas Antonopoulos is likely what you are after.  The are both open source and free on github.  https://www.youtube.com/c/RenePickhardt is another great resource if you want to listen to lectures by a Bitcoin developer.  Another good way to find lectures is to filter a YouTube search by videos longer than 20 minutes.  Reading old posts from https://bitcointalk.org/ should get you the rest of the way.  You need to know game theory, computer science, and crypto primitives for it all to make sense.

Comment: @Brandon, Thanks again ! I understand as you mention that cryptography and Game theory are essentials. In computer science do you mean Computer networks and operating systems along with Data structures and algorithms?

Comment: Well computer science is the study of algorithms and data structures. Bitcoin requires a network to operate, not necessarily the Internet, but some mechanism of transferring data between nodes, otherwise its centralized.  If you are talking about data transfer you could read about blockstream satellites, SSL, TCP/IP, onion routing, bit torrent protocol, and BTC over HAM radio. Alternatively, the byzantine generals problem, feedback loops (markov chains applied to game theory), network effects (such as the electrical grid, internet, email, or cell phone service) deal with graph theory networks.